# Code needed to convert call variable to two separate variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file exported from a PCR plate software. I need a code to convert the call variable ("Allele 1, Allele 2, Heterozygote and No Call") to the two separate variable ("G1-2 1" and "G1-2 2")

Definition

No call is blank

Allele 1 is +/+

Allele 2 is G11384M/G11384M (in superscript if this is possible in R)

Heterozygote is G11384M/+

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated

Orginal File Export

[image]

What I need

[image]

Data str

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   96 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Well: chr  "A01" "A02" "A03" "A04" ...
 $ Call: chr  "No Call" "No Call" "Allele 1" "Allele 1" ...
```

Comment: You can use a `case_when` i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(G1_21 = case_when(Call == "Allele 1" ~ "+", Call == "Heterozygote" ~ "G11384M", TRUE ~ ""))` and similarly for `G1_22`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
data = data.frame(
    Well = c("A01", "A02", "A03", "A04", "A05", "A06", "A07", "A08"),
    Call = c("No Call", "No Call", "Allele 1", "Heterozygote", "Allele 1",
             "Allele 2", "Heterozygote", "Heterozygote"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
g121map = c("No Call"="", "Allele 1"="+", "Allele 2"="G1^{1384M}",
            "Heterozygote"="G1^{1384M}")
g122map = c("No Call"="", "Allele 1"="+", "Allele 2"="G1^{1384M}",
            "Heterozygote"="+")
data["G1-21"] = g121map[data$Call]
data["G1-22"] = g122map[data$Call]
```

The data frame will now look like this:

```
> data
  Well         Call      G1-21      G1-22
1  A01      No Call                      
2  A02      No Call                      
3  A03     Allele 1          +          +
4  A04 Heterozygote G1^{1384M}          +
5  A05     Allele 1          +          +
6  A06     Allele 2 G1^{1384M} G1^{1384M}
7  A07 Heterozygote G1^{1384M}          +
8  A08 Heterozygote G1^{1384M}          +
```

You can use the exponent formatting in plots.